# How to show if two regular surfaces are diffeomorphic

Tags: differential-geometry, diffeomorphism

How can I show if regular surfaces $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2-z^2=-1$ are diffeomorphic? I know that they are not, but how can I show it?

Comment: What can you say about, e.g, the number of connected components?

Comment: one has 1 connected components and the other 2

Comment: Can you go on from there?